# MYSQL ADMIN TASK

Tags: mysql, system-administration

Can any one help me for the Mysql Administration Task,

I want information that how to maintain Database Space, index, cache etc..

Information related to secure MYSQL.

Thanks in advance!!!!
Riddhi

Answer (score -1):

What kind of maintenance are you looking to perform? Your question is not very clear.

I would suggest starting with something like [PHP My Admin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php), which will support all your basic MySQL admin tasks.  It's also free to download and use, and reasonably well supported.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your answer,

I want clear your doubts, 
Can you tell me, how to know the Database size, for that i have one query also, but if i want to increase size of that, so what can i do ?

Please send your great suggestion.